# How to pass udtt into a stored procedure in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, user-defined-types

I have a SP prc_Foo_Delete which has the following signature:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [prc_Foo_Delete]
    @fooIds [int_udtt] READONLY,
    @deleteReason int,
    @comment nvarchar(512),
    @deletedBy nvarchar(128)
```

int_udtt is define as:

```
CREATE TYPE [int_udtt] AS TABLE(
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF)
)
```

I tried to call this SP in Management Studio with following script:

```
DECLARE @return_value int
EXEC    @return_value = [prc_Foo_Delete]
        @fooIds = 3,
        @deleteReason = 2,
        @comment = N'asfdasdf',
        @deletedBy = N'asdfa'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
GO
```

The error I got is: Operand type clash: int is incompatible with int_udtt. How do I pass in a int or a list of int to call in this tool (I know how to do it in code but not in Management Studio).

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Since you've defined your user defined type as a parameter on the stored procedure, you need to **use** that user-defined type, too, when calling the stored procedure! You cannot just send in a single `INT` instead....

Try something like this:

```
-- define an instance of your user-defined table type
DECLARE @IDs [int_udtt]

-- fill some values into that table
INSERT INTO @IDs VALUES(3), (5), (17), (42)

-- call your stored proc
DECLARE @return_value int
EXEC    @return_value = [prc_Foo_Delete]
        @fooIds = @IDs,   -- pass in that UDT table type here!
        @deleteReason = 2,
        @comment = N'asfdasdf',
        @deletedBy = N'asdfa'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
GO
```