# inserting an array of user-defined data type in MS SQL server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a relationship, where a student can have multiple books. I have separate tables called Students and Books. I want to create a stored procedure such that, when I insert a student into the Students table, I also want it to insert all of his books into the Books table.

So, these are the types I defined.

```
CREATE TYPE BOOK
AS TABLE
(
    id nvarchar(36),
    title nvarchar(100),
    author nvarchar(100),
    student_id nvarchar(36)
);

CREATE TYPE STUDENT
AS TABLE
(
    id nvarchar(36),
    name nvarchar(100),
    nationality nvarchar(100),
    books BOOK 
);
```

Since a student can have multiple books, I have defined a type/TABLE for BOOK and I'm passing it inside the type for STUDENT.

But when I do this, I get the following error

> Msg 350, Level 16, State 1, Line 25 The column "books" does not have a
>   valid data type. A column cannot be of a user-defined table type.

It looks like, SQL server does not allow me to pass an array of custom objects inside a type. How can I resolve this?

This design was chosen, since it's possible that, in future, I have a type/TABLE called SCHOOL, where, a SCHOOL can have multiple STUDENT, each of which can have multiple BOOK, in which case, my SCHOOL type/TABLE would have hold an array of arrays.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass udtt into a stored procedure in SQL Server Management Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8439711/how-to-pass-udtt-into-a-stored-procedure-in-sql-server-management-studio)

Comment: This looks like a classical `1:n`-relationship. You would design tables and foreign keys to set up this relation. The `TYPE` is not meant to be used as table... It's just a defined *bundle* to be allowed to use it as parameter. Another - more flexible - way is to pass over complex parameter as one XML parameter. This allows nestings easily, but needs some extra effort to get the values out...

Comment: @Shnugo, right. Assuming this is the relationship, how do I write a Stored Procedure for inserting data into the tables?

Answer (score 0):

To be honest: This is absolute base knowledge if you deal with an RDBMS like SQL-Server. You'll find tons of tutorials...

The case you are describing seems to be a `m:n`-relationship, where you store students in one table, books in another table and their combination in a third table (called *mapping table*). Just as a start:

**Hint:** I would not use the datatype `nvarchar(36)` as id, if you do not have a very good reason for this... Easiest is `INT IDENTITY`, which will automatically use the next free integer number.

```
CREATE TABLE STUDENT
( 
    id nvarchar(36) CONSTRAINT PK_STUDENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name nvarchar(100),
    nationality nvarchar(100)
);
CREATE TABLE BOOK
(
    id nvarchar(36) CONSTRAINT PK_BOOK PRIMARY KEY,
    title nvarchar(100),
    author nvarchar(100),
);
CREATE TABLE STUDENT_BOOK
(
    student_id nvarchar(36) CONSTRAINT FK_STUDENT_BOOK_student_id FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES STUDENT(id),
    book_id nvarchar(36) CONSTRAINT FK_STUDENT_BOOK_book_id FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES BOOK(id),
    TimeOfRental DATETIME
);


INSERT INTO STUDENT VALUES
 ('abc','Jim','GB')
,('xyz','Jane','GER')

INSERT INTO BOOK VALUES
 ('b123','A short introduction to relational databases','Shnugo')
,('b786','Some ideas about m:n-relation through a mapping table','Shnugo')
,('b543','That''s enough for further self-learning','Shnugo');

INSERT INTO STUDENT_BOOK VALUES
 ('abc','b123',{d'2016-04-01'})
,('abc','b543',{d'2016-07-01'})
,('xyz','b786',{d'2016-11-01'})

SELECT s.name
      ,b.title
      ,sb.TimeOfRental
FROM STUDENT_BOOK AS sb
INNER JOIN STUDENT AS s ON sb.student_id=s.id
INNER JOIN BOOK AS b ON sb.book_id=b.id
```